# Activity.recreate() after Activity.setTheme() causes activity leak

Tags: android

I was close to publish a new update for my app until I tested it on a Android 9 Emulator. When changing the theme seamlessly (setTheme() and recreate() afterwards), the app launches one more activity per active activity. This stacks up: 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 16 -> ... and so the app gets very slow after short time (if you keep changing themes rapidly)

How do I change themes in detail?

If the user enters the settings menu through the `MainActivity`, it launches a `SettingsActivity` which sets a `SettingsFragment` as its `R.android.content`. In the `SettingsFragment` the user can choose a theme in a `ListPreference`, which if changes occure, restarts its activity (`SettingsActivity`) and notifies `MainActivity` through a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to recreate itself too with `recreate()`. In pseudo code:

```
/* In SettingsFragment */
ListPreference themes = ...
themes.onPreferenceChange() -> getActivity().recreate(); // Recreates SettingsActivity

/* In MainActivity */
recreate();
```

As said this behaviour only occures on Android 9. On Android 8.1 or below, the `MainActivity` doesn't even get destroyed as I can see through Logcat (it doesn't trigger onDestroy()).

Comment: onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called.  Are you sure that activity not still hanging around?

Comment: It shouldn't, because only one MainActivity logs that it changes themes (On Android 8.1 and below). On Android 9 there are many MainActivities logging that they are changing their themes.